# Undefined index when printing data from mysql database?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

This is the method I use to get the specific row.

```
public function getNajomca($id){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM najomca WHERE id = ".$id;
    $query = mysqli_query($this->connection, $sql);
    $udajeNajom =[];
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $udajeNajom[] = [
            'id' => $row['id'],
            'meno' => $row['meno'],
            'priez' => $row['priezvisko'],
            'adresa' => $row['adresa'],
            'idsklad' => $row['idsklad'],
            'koniec' => $row['koniecPrenajmu'],
            'telCis' => $row['telCis']
        ];
    }
    return $udajeNajom;
}
```

I have set up the __construct method everything works fine.
I have put this `$dbObject = new \BeginningPhp\Databaza("localhost", "3306", "root", "", "portalove");`
into my Header file.
And I have included it in every other file. `include 'header.php';`
But when I use the above method in this code:

```
<a id="aa">Meno: <?php echo $najomca['meno']?></a>
<a id="aa">Priezvisko: <?php echo $najomca['priez'] ?></a>
<a id="aa">Adresa: <?php echo $najomca['adresa'] ?></a>
<a id="aa">Sklad: <?php echo $najomca['idsklad'] ?></a>
<a id="aa">Koniec prenájmu: <?php echo $najomca['koniec'] ?></a>
<a id="aa">Tel. číslo: <?php echo $najomca['telCis'] ?></a>
```

It gives an error that I use a undefined index f.e. meno.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multidimensional array `$udajeNajom`. Use `foreach`.

```
foreach($udajeNajom as $index=>$item){
    echo $item['meno'];
}
```

or

```
$najomca[0]['meno']
```